# File access error when running webpack/angular-cli on Windows Ubuntu Bash in WebStorm

Tags: windows, ubuntu, bash, windows-subsystem-for-linux, webstorm

I just started using Windows Ubuntu Bash.
Everything seems working fine except one very enjoying problem.
When I run angular-cli and/or webpack server and I edit project file at the same time my IDE throws and error that it cannot save the file [clickt to see the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ClcxX.png)

It doesn't happen always but very often and always when I press save twice quickly.
It seems that somehow webpack is blocking access to the file when it detects change and the IDE cannot write the file at this point in time.

When I run the same project directly on Windows it works fine and described issue never happens.

I'll appreciate any help.

Comment: Having the same problem

Comment: @tomastrajan hi, I manage to find solution, please see the answer.

Comment: You forgot to mention the name of the IDE.

Answer (score 1):

I manage to solve the problem in two steps:

- In Settings > Apperance & Behavior > System Settings disable "Use safe write"
- Set terminal path to Ubuntu Bash `C:\Windows\System32\bash.exe` (I don't think that is matters but it's nice to integrate it)

Now everything seem to work fine.